# How to pass tf.glorot_uniform_initializer() into tf.Variable(0 not get_variable()

Tags: python, tensorflow

For `tensorflow` I would like to create a `tf` variable using `tf.Variable`

```
test = tf.Variable()
```

and using`tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()`with the `shape = [ 2 , 3 ]`

I know I can use

```
w2 =tf.get_variable( "w2" , shape = [ hiddensize ,
    outputsize ] , initializer =
    tf.glorot_uniform_initializer() , dtype =
    tf.float32
    )
```

but it may potential gets scope error, `tf.Variable()` won't.

If anyone can help me, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: tf.truncated_normal does have a version called tf.truncated_normal_glorot_uniform_initializer(), but glorot_uniform does not have a version returning tensor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an initial value from the initializer just using it as a callable:

```
test = tf.Variable(tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((2, 3)))
```